# Why do my blinds keep popping out of their mounting clips?

Tags: blinds

I have some blinds in a bedroom that fall down EVERY TIME I tug on the cord (these were here when I moved in).

There are 3 clip-in metal pieces drilled into the wall, that the blinds "snap" into (see images below). But, every time I clip in the blinds, and then tug on the cord, the blinds fall off...

I've made sure that the blinds are clipped in securely. I'm looking for a reason why this is happening, and advice on how to fix it. I'm thinking that the sellers just put up the blinds in a poor way to make the sale. But, I'd like to fix it if I can, rather than get a new set of blinds....

Note: I'm not the most handy individual, so please "dumb down" your answers.  :)

[image: Metal Brackets]
[image: Blind Bar]
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] to add a pic of the _side_ of the mounting clip and the top & back sides of the header rail. Now that I can see the image on a bigger display, that clip looks really odd.

Answer (score 6):

I see several possibilities:

1. You're yanking on the cords *way* too hard.
2. You *think* you've got the blind snapped into the clips, but one or more really aren't snapping in properly.

   - This really is *easy* to get wrong. I've installed quite a number of these blinds and they can be *very* finicky to get right.
   - Sometimes you have to change the angle of the head rail when approaching the clips to get it in right, or put the *other* edge in first.
   - I've had them fall off the clips as soon as I let go, despite having heard a "click".
   - I've had them fall off when pulling (gently) the first time.
   - Often, I've found that I have to get the blind positioned, then *hit* it (with my palm or side of my fist) to get it to properly and completely snap into the clip.
3. One or more of the clips is bent and isn't holding correctly.

   - Compare the clips against each other to see if any are different.
   - Compare them to the head rail of the blinds to see if any look wrong.
   - You may need to unscrew one from the window to fiddle with it against the head rail to ensure that it's shaped properly to latch in.

Answer (score 5):

Those clips are a pain. The key is to be sure the *front* clip is fully engaged. It should clearly wrap around the blind channel. The bracket angles down a short distance and then vertical. That vertical part needs to be fully locked down onto the channel.

If it just doesn't want to hold, try bending the front portion of the clip down slightly and the large spring tab forward to introduce more tension.

If all else fails, you may need new mounting hardware. Those clips are barely adequate even when they're in new condition and installed well.

Comment: Front clip? I only see a back clip on these brackets! Maybe that is the issue....

Comment: The bracket angles down a short distance and then vertical . That vertical part needs to be fully locked down onto the channel.

Comment: @Jabbamonkey I think he means the "toes" coming forwards roughly horizontally. It's those that are supposed to support the weight, i.e. part of the blind assembly goes above each toe in approximate contact with the top of the window recess.